# Spring Security. Аутентификация с помощью Jdbc

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Имеется собственный проект, который делается в рамках обучения. Хочу реализовать аутентификацию пользователей с помощью Jdbc и настроить ограничения на доступ к разным страницам по ролям, но столкнулся с такой проблемой, что после ввода логина\пароля получаю 403 Forbidden.

БД Postgresql

```
create table shorty_video_service.client_role
(
    role_id             bigserial  not null,
    role_name           char(50) not null,
    constraint PK_53 primary key ( role_id )
);

create table shorty_video_service.client
(
    client_id           bigserial not null,
    client_name         char(50) not null,
    role_id             bigint   not null,
    enabled             boolean not null ,
    client_second_name    char(50) not null,
    age                 int not null,
    sex                 boolean not null,
    client_password       varchar(60) not null,
    client_photo          char(255) not null,
    constraint PK_44 primary key ( client_id ),
    constraint FK_58 foreign key ( role_id ) references shorty_video_service.client_role ( role_id )
);
```

Класс SecurityConfig

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final DataSource dataSource;

protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
                .usersByUsernameQuery(
                        "select client_name, client_password, enabled from shorty_video_service.client where client_name = ?"
                )
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
                        "select client_name, role_name from shorty_video_service.client left join shorty_video_service.client_role cr on cr.role_id = client.role_id where client_name = ?"
                );

@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/registration").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/welcome").hasRole("USER")
                .and().formLogin();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

       }
```

Debug log

```
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84) ~[spring-security-core-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233) ~[spring-security-core-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.doFilterInternal(DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.java:52) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:216) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```

Если вместо hasRole установить authenticated, то после ввода данных в форму авторизации, доступ к запрашиваемой странице есть. Уже несколько дней бьюсь над проблемой, но ничего не получается

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, проблема в следующей строке:

```java
.antMatchers("/api/welcome").hasRole("USER")
```

и её нужно заменить на

```java
.antMatchers("/api/welcome").hasRole("ROLE_USER")
```

так как Spring Security по умолчанию [добавляет префикс](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33205236/spring-security-added-prefix-role-to-all-roles-name) `ROLE_` к названиям ролей (например, `ROLE_USER`).

Или попробуйте работать с authorities вместо ролей.

Comment: spring не даст вам написать .hasRole("ROLE_USER") т.к. вы сами сказали что он по умолчанию подставляет ROLE_ к роли, об этом и будет ошибка.